# Teamcity: Failed to get current version of TFS root

Tags: teamcity

Build machine is failing with following message:

Failed to get current version of TFS root

We are using TeamCity Professional 2019.1.3 (build 66439).
And using VS Build tools 2019 16.3.2.

We have not done any upgrade to TFS but updated Build tools.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Are you able to use your local machine connect to TFS sever? Suggest you also use command line to get files directly  instead of through TeamCity. This will help to narrow down if this issue related to TFS side or not.

Comment: Hi PatrickLu-MSFT, From VS I can connect to TFS and check in

Comment: Hi damodar , if so  this kind of issue may not related to TFS side, suggest you to remove TFS tag. And try to analysis the issue from environment change/tools updated, network and also TeamCity build part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you ran into [this problem](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-62254) in TeamCity. The fix will be released in 2019.1.4 version.

Comment: You can download the fixed version of TFS plugin for TeamCity 2019 there